# How do I get the VS2015 web project to build my Typescript files using TypeScript 1.8?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I have Typescript 1.0, 1.4 and 1.8 folders in my Typescript sdk folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript) and my webproject config file (x.csproj) has 1.8 set in TypeScriptToolsVersion (1.8).

However, when I build the project it appears TypeScrpit 1.4 is used:

5>PreComputeCompileTypeScript:
5>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.4\tsc.exe  --module CommonJS --sourcemap --target ES5 --noEmitOnError --locale en-US "C:\Projects\MyProject.Web\Scripts\appts.ts"
5>TypeScriptClean:

What am I missing?

Comment: Can't reproduce that issue on my machine. What's the result if you build the project through MSBuild tool directly? Could you reproduce that issue on other machine with your project? If so, share your project on the OneDrive. On the other hand, check environment variable (Path) whether there is the item for TypeScript 1.8 (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.8\), if it exists, try reinstall TypeScript for Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Open up the .csproj file in a text editor.
You need to set the following line

```
<TypeScriptToolsVersion>1.8</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
```

This can be found under Project -> PropertyGroup

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ross, however I already have set the TypeScriptToolsVersion to 1.8